# Android phonegap SpeechRecognizer issue : Cannot read property 'speechrecognizer'

Tags: android, git, cordova, speech-recognition, cordova-3

I am new to cordova-android app development.I am using `cordova 3.3.0` to create Android phonegap SpeechRecognizer application. I referred [SpeechRecognizer](http://www.excellentwebworld.com/android-speechrecognizer-plugin-phonegap-3-0/). According to that i have executed below commands to create cordova android platform app.

**1) cordova create SpeechrecognizerApp**

***2) cordova platform add android***

**3) phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/mayurloved/speechrecognizer.git**

Afer that i imported that project in eclipse and it automatically created all required packeges and made all changes in `config.xml`. Then i copied all `html` contents of example page to my `index.html` file. All is done properly, but when i run my app, log shows error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'speechrecognizer' of undefined:20
```

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Speech Recognition plugin demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="SpeechRecognizer.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function onDeviceReady(){
                console.log("Device is ready");
            }

            function recognizeSpeech() {
                var maxMatches = 5;
                var promptString = "Speak now"; // optional
                var language = "en-US";                     // optional
                window.plugins.speechrecognizer.startRecognize(function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }, function(errorMessage){
                    console.log("Error message: " + errorMessage);
                }, maxMatches, promptString, language);
            }

            // Show the list of the supported languages
            function getSupportedLanguages() {
                window.plugins.speechrecognizer.getSupportedLanguages(function(languages){
                    // display the json array
                    alert(languages);
                }, function(error){
                    alert("Could not retrieve the supported languages : " + error);
                });
            }

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
        </script>

        <button onclick="recognizeSpeech();">Start recognition</button>
        <button onclick="getSupportedLanguages();">Get Supported Languages</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I haven't copied `SpeechRecognizer.js` in **www** folder as according to above link i don't require to copy it in my app because i am using cordova version >3.0. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: you can check if the following file is present in your project (if it's not, remove-reinstall the plugin) platforms\android\assets\www\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.speech\SpeechRecognizer.js

Comment: i did remove-reinstall thing many times but its not adding `SpeechRecognizer.js` in `www` folder. Even its not creating any kind of folder `platforms\android\assets\www\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.speech`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you launch `phonegap build android` after you add the plugin? When you install plugins, they are installed only in the /plugins folder of the project but not in the platform folder.

You have to run `phonegap build` or `phonegap prepare` for any platform to have the plugin fully installed.

And then after you can refresh the project in eclipse and you should see the java part of the plugin in the /src folder and the javascript in /assets/www/plugins

---

If the folder platforms\android\assets\www\plugins... is not there after the build, that may be because your project got corrupted.

In that case you can try to empty the plugins folder at the root of your project and re-install all plugins.

If that's not enough, you can retry emptying both platforms and plugins folder (think to save any customisation you may have done in platforms folders).

Comment: i executed `phonegap prepare` command and its working..thanks mate.